# Insert a spreadsheet into DreamWeaver

Tags: html, excel, dreamweaver

Is it possible to insert a spreadsheet into DreamWeaver? I don't want to import the spreadsheet. I want to be able to download the spreadsheet directly from the web page.

Comment: I do not want to change the file type to htm as I need it to fit into the current structure of my website

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Just PUT the Excel file to the site and add something like:

```
<a href="http://www.yoursite.com/spreadsheets/yourspreadshet.xls">Download Spreadsheet</a>
```

On your page.